# Generating a sequential number for app-wide use

Tags: groovy, grails

I have to generate a sequential number for **groovy-grails** app wide use and came up with the following.  However, is there a better way to do this?

Domain classes:

```
class RoastIdCounter {
    int counter =0
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

This one has no views or controller associated with it.  It's purely for db interaction in a service class.

```
class RoastId {
    Family family
    Integer nextId
    long timeCreated = new Date().time

    static constraints = {
        family()
        nextId()
    }
    static belongsTo = [ Family ]
}

class Family  extends {

    String farmId;
    String welcome;
    String familyName;
    String ourFarm;
    String howMuchDoWeGetPaid;

    SortedSet pictureAlbums;
    SortedSet pictures;

    Integer pictureAlbumsCount = 0;
    Integer picturesCount = 0;

    Date dateCreated = new Date()
    Date lastUpdated = new Date()

    static hasMany = [ roastIds : RoastId, pictureAlbums : PictureAlbum, pictures : Picture ]

    static constraints = {
        farmId()
        familyName( )
        welcome( widget:'textarea' )
        ourFarm( widget:'textarea' )
        howMuchDoWeGetPaid( widget:'textarea' )

        dateCreated()
        lastUpdated()
}

    String toString() { "$farmId - $familyName" }

} // Family
```

Service class for dealing with the number generation:

```
class RoastIdCounterService {

    static transactional = true

    def getNextRoastId() {

        def ric = RoastIdCounter.list()[-1]

        if( ric != null ){
            ric.lock()
            ric.counter = ric.counter + 1
            ric.save()
            return ric.counter
        } else {
            return -1 
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

Here I'm just sending the object all pre-populated:

```
def create = {
    def roastIdInstance = new RoastId()
    roastIdInstance.properties = params
    roastIdInstance.nextId = roastIdCounterService.getNextRoastId()
    return [roastIdInstance: roastIdInstance]
}
```

Environment: Grails 1.3.7, PostgreSql 8.4

Would there be a better way to do this? What potential problems am I overlooking?

Comment: Can you not simply declare the column in the db as auto increment?

Comment: Normally yes. I don't remember why exactly we opted not to do that though. I think we had to have it BEFORE persisting the details of the roast. It was not an ordinary ID column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using an [AtomicLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) instead of the RoastIdCounterService? You can then call [AtomicLong.incrementAndGet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet%28%29) to get the next value. The atomic long will take care of the locking required for safe concurrent access.

Comment: No, I don't think so, good point.